# Donut Icing doesn't seem to clip correctly

Tags: modeling

I've been following the Blender Beginner Tutorial, but when I've reached the donut icing, there are weird darker pixels on it. Putting the Clip Start lower as he did in the tutorial only seems to make it worse, putting it higher only makes it limitedly better.

[image: Screenshot of Donut issue]

Comment: Scale the icing to be larger.  If you used the solidify modifier, it's now intersecting with the donut.
Or move the icing up.
Or the solidify modifier wasn't 'thick' enough and it's intersecting with itself.
"Start clip" has nothing to do with anything, that's just the *camera* clipping, not the objects.

Comment: @Mike this helped, thank you!

Comment: Since it solved the problem, I added it as an "answer".  Please "accept as answer", if it is correct.  ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scale the icing to be larger. If you used the solidify modifier, it's now intersecting with the donut. Or move the icing up. Or the solidify modifier wasn't 'thick' enough and it's intersecting with itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could try pressing alt s to make the icing thicker/thinner.
Before alt s
[image]

After alt s
[image]